# NSPlaceHolderString leaking, Instruments isn't telling me where?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, instruments, foundation

I've recently finished my first iPhone app that I'm actually planning to submit, and I'm trying to clear out all the leaks. However there's one that I just can't seem to track down, and Instruments isn't really helping me either. Essentially, I've made something like a to-do list app (that's not really important though) and every time a user deletes a to-do, instruments registers a leak.

Instead of me trying to explain further, here's a screenshot:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1426380/Screen%20shot%202011-02-09%20at%2021.51.09.png

So instead of telling my exactly where the leak is coming from (like with previous leaks I've fixed), iInstruments just points to somewhere in the foundation library. It's only leaking 16B each time, so it's not really an issue of crashing, but I'm simply interested as to what is causing this.

I would love to post some code, but since I have no idea where the leak is originating, I have no idea what to post. If someone had an insight on what might be causing this, I'd be happy to oblige.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Here's another screenshot as requested by @Moshe. I'm new to instruments so I didn't even realise that the right panel existed until now!

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1426380/Screen%20shot%202011-02-10%20at%2007.55.58.png

Comment: It seems that your screenshot is not the complete Instruments window. It would be helpful if you can post a complete screenshot. Show the right panel too please.

Comment: Oh, welcome to StackOverflow. You can post an image in your post by Clicking on the image icon in the editor above the textbox.

Comment: I added an edit with the right panel shown. I would have posted the actual picture, however I can't until I've got >10 reputation, so I just left a direct link instead.

Comment: In the right panel, the stack is shown. The methods shown with the black icon next to then are yours. Can I see `saveNag` and `initWithName:numberOfNags` please? Those are the functions that seem to contain the problem.

Comment: Ahh, caught it. Thanks to your tip, I noticed that in the initWithName:numberOfnags: method, I'd set a UILocalNotification alertAction like so: notification.alertAction = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Ok"]];. No idea why, but I corrected it and no leaks are now reported. So thanks! As I'm new here, how do I go about marking that as solving my question?

Comment: On the left side of my question there should be an "empty checkmark". Click on it to fill it in.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest running "Build and Analyze". (In the Build Menu, or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>).

If that returns nothing, it could be that an Apple framework is leaking. If that is the case, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Ahh, ok, thanks for the help anyway. I guess it must be something I can't do anything about.

Comment: See my comments to your question.